# Expose a POJO as a Websevice in Mule via Configuration _Only_?

Tags: jax-ws, cxf, esb, mule, spring-integration

> #### Technologies Involved

- Mule
- Apache CXF

> #### Given

A simple POJO (controversial acronym, but let's say a smart POJO):

```
public class SmartPojo implements SomeBusinessInterface {

    public String doSomethingSmart( With something ) {

        String result;

        result = Irrelevant.process( something )

        return result;
    }
}
```

> #### Need to Achieve

Expose `SmartPojo` as a Webservice *without* touching the code ( *without*: changing `SmartPojo`, changing `SmartPojoInterface`, adding a new interface, any JAX-WS annotations, etc ). The goal is to use Mule configuration **only**.

I can easily do it with Spring Integration, and would appreciate any input on how to achieve it with Mule. ( It seems that "cxf:inbound-endpoint" needs to be configured with "method-entry-point-resolver" + providing my WSDL in some way.. or another direction? )

Thank you

Comment: As the question is phrased the spring-integration tag seems out of place. Spring Integration could help you, but not while using Mule configuration only.

Comment: Spring Integration is an alternative to Mule, and there I can easily do it. Don't see what is out of place here.

Answer (score 1):

> CXF will use reflection to examine the public methods of your component class and expose
>   them as SOAP operations in the wsdl.

This quote comes straight from Mule In Action. (page 58)

If you are trying to expose every public method in your class as a SOAP operation, then this is the approach you should take.

From your explict call above, it looks like you may want to implement a REST-ful or REST-like interface, not a SOAP interface.  You would not use cxf to implement that.  You would probably need to look at http://www.mulesoft.org/display/MULE/Mule+RESTpack.

Comment: You don't just switch SOAP for REST or the other way around. They are not interchangeable.